# How to reclaim space taken by an index that partially built and was terminated by a power outage

Tags: postgresql, index, postgresql-9.4, disk-space, vacuum

I'm running postgres (postgis) 9.4.2 on a mac (10.10.4).

I've got a couple big tables (several TBs).

During an index build on one of them that takes about a week, I watched the available HD space drop as you'd expect to nearly the point at which the index would be finished  when a power outage lasted longer than the battery unit and the system went down. I had buffers off, and `fillfactor=100` during the build since it's a static datasource. On reboot, the available space left on the drive is exactly where it was at nearly the end of the index build. Vacuum analyze doesn't free the space.

I tried dropping the table and re-ingesting, and that didn't drop the space. Now I'm at a place where I don't have enough space to build the index.

Are the files generated during the index build stuck in some limbo where they can't be removed by the system because of the way the machine went down during the power outage?

When I look at the table sizes + indexes in the db (which is the only data on that drive) they add up to about **6TB**.  The drive is **8TB**, and there is less than **500GB** left on the drive, so it seems there are about 1.5TB lost somewhere which is about the size that index would have been.

Any ideas?

Comment: Is the index still listed with a query like this?

`SELECT r.relname, r.relkind, n.nspname FROM pg_class r INNER JOIN pg_namespace n ON r.relnamespace = n.oid WHERE relkind = 'i';`

Comment: No, it doesn't show up in the results from that query.

Comment: Do you have anything in the list that `SELECT indexrelid::regclass, indrelid::regclass FROM pg_catalog.pg_index WHERE NOT indisvalid;` gives you?

Comment: Nope, that comes up empty.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Normally we'd expect that when postgres was restarted, the crash recovery process would have removed files related to a rollback'ed index from the data directory.

Let's assume that it didn't work, or at least that it has to be checked manually.

The list of files that should be in the datadir can be established with a query like this:

```
select pg_relation_filenode(oid)
   from pg_class
  where relkind in ('i','r','t','S','m')
    and reltablespace=0
  order by 1;
```

`reltablespace=0` is for the default tablespace. If the problematic index was created in a non-default tablespace, this `0` must be replaced by its OID in `pg_tablespace`.

i,r,t,S,m in `relkind` correspond respectively to indexes, tables, toast space, sequences, materialized views. All these objects have their data in files whose names match `pg_relation_filenode(oid)`.

On disk, the data files are below `$PGDATA/base/oid/` where `oid` is the `oid` of the database obtained by `select oid,datname from pg_database`.
If we're not talking about the default tablespace, `base` is replaced by `PG_version_somelabel` instead.

List and sort the files matching relfilenodes in that directory:

```
ls | grep -E '^[0-9]+$' | sort -n > /tmp/list-of-relations.txt
```

(that actually keeps only the first segment for relations that are larger than 1Gb. If there are lingering segments not attached to anything they should be considered separately)

and diff that file with the result of the query above.

If there are lingering data files that do not correspond to any object that the db knows about, they should appear in that diff.

Comment: Awesome!  

I found 1 file in the datadir that didn't show in the select list.  Can I safely remove that file?

Comment: Actually it corresponds to about 800 files with iterations after the dot - all like 499807.484 etc.Can I safely remove those files?

Comment: @dkitchel: that would be segments of 1Gb each for the huge index. Maybe check that their timestamps coincide with when the create index was running. As for deleting them, well, I hope my reasoning above is correct, but it's your data, so ultimately it's your decision!

Comment: Yes, the timestamps are consistent with when the index was building, and the sum of the file sizes about corresponds with how big the index should be.  Your reasoning seems solid.  I'll give it a go with high confidence.  Thanks a ton.

Comment: Just following up so others who find themselves in the same predicament can use @DanielVerite's solution with confidence.   His solution did indeed work perfectly for me.

Comment: I've created a bash script of the above answer: https://gist.github.com/exhuma/4c6ee9349f74f82cfb1d @DanielVérité does it look correct to you?