# What parts make up pg_database_size?

Tags: postgresql, monitoring, statistics

I'm trying to write a munin plugin to graph DB sizes. Alongside using `pg_database_size` I want to graph the components thereof as well.

So far, I've come up with the following:

```
SELECT
    SUM(pg_relation_size(oid, 'main')) AS main_size,
    SUM(pg_relation_size(oid, 'vm')) AS vm_size,
    SUM(pg_relation_size(oid, 'fsm')) AS fsm_size,
    SUM(
        CASE reltoastrelid
        WHEN 0 THEN 0
        ELSE pg_total_relation_size(reltoastrelid)
        END
    ) AS toast_size,
    SUM(pg_indexes_size(oid)) AS indexes_size
    FROM pg_class
    WHERE reltype != 0 -- 0=indices, covered by pg_indexes_size
```

However, summing up those 5 values returns me something which is *not* the same as the result of `pg_database_size`. The difference seems to be less significant for larger DBs.

Example on a larger DB:

```
┌──────────┬────────┬─────────┬─────────┬──────────┬───────────────┬──────────────────┬─────────┐
│   main   │   vm   │   fsm   │  toast  │ indexes  │ sum_of_values │ pg_database_size │  diff   │
├──────────┼────────┼─────────┼─────────┼──────────┼───────────────┼──────────────────┼─────────┤
│ 72441856 │ 753664 │ 2392064 │ 4677632 │ 41377792 │ 116 MB        │ 111 MB           │ 5222 kB │
└──────────┴────────┴─────────┴─────────┴──────────┴───────────────┴──────────────────┴─────────┘
(1 row)
```

Example on a smaller DB:

```
┌─────────┬────────┬─────────┬────────┬─────────┬───────────────┬──────────────────┬─────────┐
│  main   │   vm   │   fsm   │ toast  │ indexes │ sum_of_values │ pg_database_size │  diff   │
├─────────┼────────┼─────────┼────────┼─────────┼───────────────┼──────────────────┼─────────┤
│ 2809856 │ 385024 │ 1351680 │ 557056 │ 2924544 │ 7840 kB       │ 6642 kB          │ 1198 kB │
└─────────┴────────┴─────────┴────────┴─────────┴───────────────┴──────────────────┴─────────┘
(1 row)
```

What am I missing?

<strike>Maybe related, maybe not: I'm shocked to see the index size. They are HUGE. Is something in my query wrong?</strike>

---

Here is a script I used to inspect the different values:

```
SELECT
    SUM(pg_relation_size(oid, 'main')) AS main,
    SUM(pg_relation_size(oid, 'vm')) AS vm,
    SUM(pg_relation_size(oid, 'fsm')) AS fsm,
    SUM(
        CASE reltoastrelid
        WHEN 0 THEN 0
        ELSE pg_total_relation_size(reltoastrelid)
        END
    ) AS toast,
    SUM(pg_indexes_size(oid)) AS indexes,
    pg_size_pretty(
        SUM(pg_relation_size(oid, 'main'))::bigint +
        SUM(pg_relation_size(oid, 'vm'))::bigint +
        SUM(pg_relation_size(oid, 'fsm'))::bigint +
        SUM(pg_indexes_size(oid))::bigint +
        SUM(
            CASE reltoastrelid
            WHEN 0 THEN 0
            ELSE pg_total_relation_size(reltoastrelid)
            END
        )::bigint
    ) AS sum_of_values,
    pg_size_pretty(pg_database_size(current_database())) AS pg_database_size,

    pg_size_pretty(
        SUM(pg_relation_size(oid, 'main'))::bigint +
        SUM(pg_relation_size(oid, 'vm'))::bigint +
        SUM(pg_relation_size(oid, 'fsm'))::bigint +
        SUM(pg_indexes_size(oid))::bigint +
        SUM(
            CASE reltoastrelid
            WHEN 0 THEN 0
            ELSE pg_total_relation_size(reltoastrelid)
            END
        )::bigint - pg_database_size(current_database())::bigint
    ) AS diff

FROM pg_class
WHERE reltype != 0;
```

Comment: Scratch that about the indices being huge. By default RRD picks a lower limit for the graphs if not set. In this case it was not 0, and I was not really parsing the values in my head, just looking at the pretty pictures. Turns out setting the lower-limit to 0 resolves that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`pg_database_size()` essentially queries the filesystem for the size of
  `$PGDATA/base/oid-of-database` (the per-database data directory), plus the size of every such directory in non-default tablespaces added with `CREATE TABLESPACE`.

If there are files in these directories that don't pertain to any relation , they will be counted too. Looking at a random database, I can see `pg_internal.init`, `PG_VERSION`, `pg_filenode.map` that are in that case. They add up to the directory size and will not be counted in any control query.

Stray data files may also exist. See [How to reclaim space taken by an index that partially built and was terminated by a power outage](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/109092) for a concrete example. They also can't be found by querying against `pg_class`, by definition, and they're counted in the db size on disk.

Concerning the query, just for the purpose of getting the sum of objects sizes, I'd suggest a simpler version:

```
select sum(pg_total_relation_size(oid)) 
from pg_class
where relkind in ('r','m','S')
  and not relisshared
```

Note that shared relations are removed from this query (`not relisshared`). Shared objects are visible from all databases and don't belong to any database's directory, they're in `$PGDATA/global`. One of the shared tables that is expected to be significant in size is [`pg_shdepend`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/catalog-pg-shdepend.html).
Overlooking this in your original query makes it overestimate (in addition to @jjanes comment about toast tables).

Comment: Thanks. This confirms my suspicions that something must be different about `pg_database_size`. I've fixed the toast issue, and I've now got something much more tangible. I'll also add the `relisshared` filter which seems like a very good idea in general ;)

Answer (score 4):

You are counting the toast tables twice.  Once under their owner, as `pg_total_relation_size(reltoastrelid)`, and again under their own entry in pg_class.  You should use relkind, not reltype, to filter what you want.

Also, trying to micromanage your RDBMS to this extent rarely pays off.

Comment: This cuts down on the difference, but there's still a difference. The tip about "relkind" was quite interesting. I'll continue my search.  Also, this is not about micromanagement. I was coming across these values while working on a graph and thought I could add these values as well. Graphing is a funny thing. Usually you know that you need the values only after an anomaly.

Comment: I checked on a couple of different DBs right now, and they all show a difference of exactly 654kB. That's good enough for graphing I guess, I'm still curious where this comes from though.